# Php code in a game

Tags: php, function

To start off, sorry for my bad English.

Hello! I just started working with codes.  To start off, I had the assignment to make a very easy game. It is built with PHP and is not very difficult.

Here is the code:

```
<?php
    function hoger7() {
        echo ("<div class="totaal">")

        $totaal = $d1 + $d2 ;
        echo "= $totaal";
        echo ("</div>");

        echo ("<div class="container gewonnen">");
        if ($totaal > 7) {
            echo "<font color='green'>Gefeliciteerd, u heeft gewonnen!</font>";
        };
        if ($totaal < 7){
            echo "<font color='red'>Helaas, u heeft verloren</font>";
        };
        if ($totaal == 7){
            echo "<font color='orange'>U heeft een prijs gewonnen!</font>";
            echo ("<button type='button' onclick=location.href='http://www.fopwebshop.mvgz.nl/?product=luchtbedvulling'>Klik hier voor je Prijs!</button>");
        };
        echo ("</div>");

        echo ("<div class="image1">");
        echo "<img src='images/$d1.png'/>";
        echo ("</div>");

        echo("<div class="image2">");
        echo "<img src='images/$d2.png'/>";
        echo ("</div>");
    };
?>
```

It's quite messy, but please ignore that. So, I want to recall this function like this:

```
<?php
    if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
        $selected_val = $_POST['h'];  // Storing Selected Value In Variable
        hoger7();
    }
?>
```

But, it gives me a blank page. If you need anymore codes please tell me below:D

Friendly greetings,

Jesse

Comment: Enable `display_errors`, there is a fatal error.

Comment: ^and do error_reporting(E_ALL);

Comment: The if statement prevents your function from running if the page is just loaded and not posted to by a form with a submit button

Comment: Beyond the "fatal error" issue where are you learning this starting php from?  

Whatever the source, it may well not be a good place to try to learn from.  
My suggestion is to search around github.com for a simple php game that is coded more cleanly, and then play around with someone else's php code for a while, just to see how someone else does it before you learn bad habits yourself and get stuck with them in the future.

Comment: Ok, I take that back, when I look around github, most of the "simple games" there are crap.  Instead, I really recommend trying out codecademy when you get time:
http://www.codecademy.com/en/tracks/php Maybe they'll be able to help you there from falling into some of the traps that php is famous for, and makes it easy for new php coders to fall into.

Comment: So many syntax errors...

Comment: I know its messy, im learning in a class with a very bad teacher so most of this is improvised i only have 2 months of work with coding so i dont know whats good and whats not. But the best part is it must work.

Answer (score 1):

On the first line in the function you're missing a `;` after the `echo`, and you need to escape the double-quotes.

Change it to this :

```
echo ("<div class=\"totaal\">");
```

Or use simple quotes `'`.

As suggested in the comments, turn on the error reporting, it will tell you when there's an error like this.

Answer (score 0):

i think the `$_POST['submit']` is coming from your submit button.
add a hidden field
`<input type='hidden' name = 'submit' value='1'>`

I'm not sure if submit button outputs any post data. anyways, it's better to use hidden field. that will take care of `if(isset($_POST['submit']))`

if that is not your problem, `echo` the `$selected_val` values and see if they are the values you were expecting.